# Can 'Since' be used as 'When'?

Tags: word-meaning

I see two pictures where 'since' are used as 'when'

> **'Since the beginning, it was just the same. The only difference, the crowds are bigger now.'**

https://izquotes.com/quote/elvis-presley/since-the-beginning-it-was-just-the-same-the-only-difference-the-crowds-are-bigger-now-148532

> **'Since my childhood, I saw my elder brothers playing cricket and that is what built my passion around it. I was enrolled in school but all my attention was on cricket.'**

https://www.azquotes.com/quote/1563531

Comment: But "since" doesn't mean "when" in your examples. The expression ***since X*** (where ***X*** is some identifiable point in the past, such as "the beginning of time" or "my childhood") means ***from X (in the past) until now***.

Answer (score 2):

*Since* does not mean *when*. It means "**over a period of time starting with**". That fits both of your examples (though the grammar of the first is possibly slightly non-standard). It usually means that the period of time is continuing to 'now', but in actual usage that is not universal - and not even formally required if it is used in relation to a past perfect verb.

It also means *because*, but that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

### Since means continuously from a point in time in the past until now

I would recommend a slightly changed wording.

> Since the beginning, it *has been* just the same. The only difference *is that* the crowds are bigger now.

### If you mean ONLY at a point in time, you can use "in"

> In the beginning, it was just the same. The only difference is that the crowds are bigger now.
>
> In my childhood, I saw my elder brothers playing cricket and that is what built my passion around it. I was enrolled in school but all my attention was on cricket.'

Comment: Or that was normal grammar for his dialect. There is no ultimate authority for what is '*right*' in English.

Comment: Agreed, he is the King after all!